# How to Check and Uncheck all checkbox in angular 7

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

Hi i'm creating an application where i get data from an api and i have two check boxes one is outside and one is inside loop. I'm looping the data from server like this.[image]

and i'm getting the data like this:
[image]

what i want is to check or uncheck the heading checkbox and all the other checkbox can cheked or uncheked. I can't seem to understand how to do it.
Data is coming from api so o don't know the size of checkboxes. How can i perform this function? i can use event change but i don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a boolean value for maintaining the status of the List whether selected or not.
For example - 
[checked] = "true" or [checked] = "false";

In your database maintain the list likewise for each item make sure you have a boolean value whether its selected or not